# Apache spark maven tomcat:run

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, apache-spark

I want to run Apache Spark from a spring project with multiple maven module.
Spring project running correctly without apache spark dependency but when I added spark dependency I see the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

spark dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-assembly-jar</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you try to add servlet api dependency as provided . E.g. `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me. Reason is spark engine has transitive dependencies to a particular version of servlet api and implementation. In the classpath it finds first smth different and complains about it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Also in order to use web service as a driver I believe it's required to use compile scope of the spark libraries.